# Наследование свойств

Tags: php, наследование

Есть такой код:

```html
<?php 

  class User {
    public $userName; 
 private $userPassword;

  function __construct($userName, $userPassword) {
    $this->userName = $userName;
  $this->userPassword = $userPassword;
  }

  function reg() {
    echo "<br> User with name $this->userName registrated";
  }
  }

  class Car extends User {
  protected $userCar;

    function __construct($userCar) {
    $this->userCar = $userCar;
    }
  
  function regCar() {
    echo "<br> Car $this->userCar registrated for user $this->userName";
  }
  }
  
  $userName = 'The Tux';
  $userPassword = '123';
  $userCar = 'Subaru';

  $user = new User($userName, $userPassword); 

  $car = new Car($userCar);

  $user->reg();
  $car->regCar();
  $car->reg();
```

Как в классе Car получить значение userName? Не совсем понял смысл наследования? Присваивать значение объекту: $car->userName = $user->userName? Или через конструктор класса Car?

Comment: а зачем машине userName? и вообще почему машина расширяет юзера? О______________________О

Comment: Это просто пример. Задача понять наследование? А именно как обращаться к переменной родительского класса

Comment: Юзер должен владеть машиной, а не машина должна знать что-то о своем владельце

Comment: не не не. так не пойдет. пример должен быть корректным с любой точки зрения. а то сейчас будем говорить как крабу унаследовать кошачий хвост и как сделать, чтоб лавочка говорила имена тех, кто на ней сидит, основываясь по опечатку полупопий.

Comment: Если не можете помочь - не засоряйте комментарии, пожалуйста

Comment: @sv458 в классе Car обратитесь к свойству userName через ключевое слово parent. Пример:  parent::userName;

Comment: Похоже вы сами себе не хотите помочь. ну удачи в шлакостроении

Comment: @Эдуард не работает, пробовал

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы конкретный пример привести можете? Или только потрепаться здесь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не верно понимаете наследование. И ваш пример действительно бессмысленный, при помощи него нельзя ничего изучить и понять зачем наследование нужно.

Приведу более понятный пример:

```
<?php

interface Info
{
    public function info();
}

abstract class Named
{
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class User extends Named
{
    private $password;

    public function __construct($name, $password) {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->password = $password;
    }
}

class Car extends Named implements Info
{
    protected $owner;

    public function __construct($name, User $owner) {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->owner = $owner;
    }

    public function info() {
        return "This is car " . $this->getName() . ". Owner is user " . $this->owner->getName() . ".";
    }
}
```

Здесь класс `Пользователь` расширяет класс `Именуемый` и дополняет его дополнительным приватным свойством `Пароль`. Класс `Машина` расширяет класс `Именуемый`, дополняет его защищённым свойством `Владелец` и также может возвращать информацию о себе.

```
$user1 = new User("Ivan", "Qwe");
$car = new Car("Subaru", $user1);
$user2 = new User("Petr", "Asdf");

print_r([
    $user1->getName(),
    $car->getName(),
    $car->info(),
    $user2->getName(),
]);
```

Здесь `print_r` выведет следующее:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Ivan
    [1] => Subaru
    [2] => This is car Subaru. Owner is user Ivan.
    [3] => Petr
)
```

Если вы поймёте как оно работает, то первый, третий и четвёртый вопросы отпадут сами по себе